# SQL Server Select Statement Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Original Query:

```
select StudyID, count(CompletedDate), count(Removed), count(RemovalReason)
from Study a
full outer join Households b
on a.HouseholdID = b.HouseholdID
where StudyID = '123456'
and Removed = 1
and RemovalReason = 5
group by StudyID
```

How do I write out this query so that for each column (CompletedDate, Removed, and RemovalReason) is not restricted to the conditions (i.e. Removed = 1, Removal Reason = 5) and only applies to the specific column. If I execute this query, it will not show me the total count for CompletedDate because I'm restricting it to these conditions. Is there a way to write it directly next to count?

Table/Columns - Study:
HouseholdID (primary key),
StudyID,
CompletedDate

Table/Columns - Households:
HouseholdID (primary key),
Removed,
RemovalReason

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  A `full join` with a `where` clause generally does not make sense.  Plus, there is no indication where the columns are coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this, but your question is a little loose with details:

```
select StudyID
    , count(CompletedDate)
    , sum(case when Removed = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
    , sum(case when RemovalReason = 5 then 1 else 0 end)
from Study a
  join Households b
       on a.HouseholdID = b.HouseholdID
where StudyID = '123456'
group by StudyID
```